# XML validation fails in debug, works in release

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio, xerces-c

My project used to run fine but now somehow I can't run my program with the debug configuration, it will exits mentioning the xml has tags that are not allowed (and give you a list of tags allowed, which you can clearly see is part of it as per this example).

> Message: element '**dataTypes**' is not allowed for content model '(identification,objectInstances,objectClasses,eventClasses,
>   dimensions?,transportations?,pipes,**dataTypes**,connections,notes)'

Both the release and debug uses the same validation file and xml file and there's no special typedef or anything.

To make sure it's working, I make sure to only use debug dependencies when running in debug but still it's not working.

I'm using xerces 3.1.1 if that matters.

Comment: What does "can't run my program" mean? What, precisely, do you see that is different than what you expect?

Comment: Edited my question, hope this is more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Codesynthesis XSD](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/download.xhtml) to generate the classes to use Xerces. It will make your life lot simpler.